# How to disable automatic app scaling in iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, size, screen, scale, ios8

I'm working today with Xcode 6.0 and the iOS 8 simulator to adjust my iOS apps to iOS 8.

The apps are automatically scaled to fit the iPhone 6/6+ screens. I do not want this, I want to arrange myself the display. How can I do that?

Furthermore, when I do this on the iPhone 6 simulator:

```
NSLog(@"%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
```

It returns :

```
320.000000
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to add an iPhone 4.7" and iPhone 5.5" launch screen.

Comment: This is the first thing I did but it had no effect, app is still scaled.

Comment: It works perfectly in 4 of my apps. Are you using assets library?

Comment: Damn, with all these sizes of app icons and launch screen, I made some mistakes in the 5.5" launch screen size... With correct size, it works. Thanks rckoenes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From rckoenes response:

> You need to add an iPhone 4.7" and iPhone 5.5" launch screen.

Be careful to the sizes of the launch screens... at this time, with exactly 14 launch screens of different sizes, it's posible to make mistakes...